# Complex MySQL CONCAT with encryption issue

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I have a value that I store into a database as a primary key, in this case we'll call it `prime_key`. I encrypt `prime_key` with the same exact encryption using PHP, so I can generate an button in HTML, for AJAX, so the user can't make up a key and delete someone else's account information.

PHP concat looks like:

```
md5('ab'.sha1('wonderful'.$prime_key.'really').'testThis');
```

MySQL CONCAT looks like:

```
$db->query("DELETE * FROM somewhere WHERE MD5(CONCAT('ab',SHA1(CONCAT('wonderful',prime_key,'really')),'testThis'))='{$_POST['altered_key']}'");
```

Notice `prime_key` is a column name in the `somewhere` table, when looking at the MySQL. I've narrowed down the problem to this exactly. It just won't DELETE. Please Help.

Comment: php's md5 and sha1 may not return the same values as mysql's version

Comment: @Dagon, why this then?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795049/will-phps-sha1-and-mysqls-sha-give-the-same-result

Comment: @Dagon - do you have an example of them returning a different value, or a link to somewhere that explains why that would ever happen?

Comment: sorry, it was a blonde moment.

Comment: Keep in mind that doing a query on a complex function like this is *extremely* inefficient — it forces a full table scan on every query. It will perform badly on large databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that

```
DELETE * FROM somewhere
```

should just be

```
DELETE FROM somewhere
```

Comment: Thanks @dave, I'm not really a MySQL expert. In time. In time.